# Does Yahoo BOSS (version 2) allow automated search queries?

Tags: yahoo-boss-api

As far I know, Yahoo BOSS (version 1) didn't allow this. But with the new payed model, does it mean you're allowed to do automated search queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With version 2 you're allowed to do an unlimited number of requests (if you pay for that).